# Oracle not using an index in a simple query, despite the hint

Tags: oracle

I have a table with column *status*. It is a string nullable column. I also have an index on this field only. Why is the following query not using the index?

```
select /*+ index(m IDX_STATUS) */ * from messages m where m.status = :1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query without named (bind) parameters. Sometimes that makes a big difference.

```
select * from messages m where m.status = 'P'
```

It may turn out that you don't even need a hint to trigger index usage.

A possible explanation is that the column contains many equal values, for example 90% of rows has `status = 'D'` (**low-cardinality column**). Now we can understand Oracle, why it did not use the index :) It simply doesn't make sense on value 'D', but is reasonable for other values. I would prefer Oracle to consider my hint (*I know better*), but that seems undoable.

In general there is an extremely useful guide [Oracle SQL Tuning Guide: The index is being ignored](http://www.orafaq.com/tuningguide/not%20using%20index.html). Still it does not mention the situation, where omitting bind parameter makes the problem go away. That's why I insisted on asking the question on SO.